# HTML5 / js - how to animate straight line between two coordinates?

Tags: jquery, html

Simple enough question (could be wrong)

im looking to animate between two points in a straight line, using HTML5 and/or Jquery.

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0); // a
ctx.lineTo(100, 100); // b
ctx.stroke();
```

http://jsbin.com/enobes

EDIT : I ended up developing a library for svg path animation http://lazylinepainter.info/

[image: example]

Comment: What you want say with *animate*?

Comment: i'll make a diagram ... one moment

Comment: You need to draw *n* different lines, each one bigger than the last, by redrawing the canvas. Smoothness comes from the difference in height on each redraw.

Comment: This solution won't apply to curved lines, ha? Any ideas how you could go about that?

Comment: hi Roozbeh, checkout this http://lazylinepainter.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks valli-R and Zevan,

I've coded an amalgam of your two answers which uses lerp with requestAnimFrame

http://jsbin.com/enobes/6

Answer (score 17):

You could use a linear interpolation or lerp. Something like this. Here is an example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UtmTh/ and here is the main code:

```
var canvas = $("#paper")[0];
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");

var startX = 50;
var startY = 50;
var endX = 100;
var endY = 100;
var amount = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    amount += 0.05; // change to alter duration
    if (amount > 1) amount = 1;
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    c.strokeStyle = "black";
    c.moveTo(startX, startY);
    // lerp : a  + (b - a) * f
    c.lineTo(startX + (endX - startX) * amount, 
             startY + (endY - startY) * amount);
    c.stroke();
}, 30);​
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check this out : http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/ it is fairly easy to do, after reading it you should be able to do it! There is also an example.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

HTML :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas">
    </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

JS :

```
var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0); // a
ctx.lineTo(100, 100); // b
ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: yeah, that draws the line, but doesn't animate between the two points...  http://jsbin.com/enobes/    It would be ideal if i could set a time and easing equation

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, not sure if it is what you are after, can explain anything you are not sure of:

```
var frame = function () { // http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
        return window.requestAnimationFrame  ||
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
          window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
          window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
          function (callback) {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
              callback(+new Date())
            }, 10)
          }
      }()

var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var easeing = {bouncePast: function (pos) {  //just a sample to show easing
                if (pos < (1 / 2.75)) {
                  return (7.5625 * pos * pos);
                } else if (pos < (2 / 2.75)) {
                  return 2 - (7.5625 * (pos -= (1.5 / 2.75)) * pos + .75);
                } else if (pos < (2.5 / 2.75)) {
                  return 2 - (7.5625 * (pos -= (2.25 / 2.75)) * pos + .9375);
                } else {
                  return 2 - (7.5625 * (pos -= (2.625 / 2.75)) * pos + .984375);
                }
              } }

function animate(x1,y1,x2,y2, duration, ease) {  //your main animation loop
    var start = +new Date();
    frame(run);
    function run(t) {
        var delta =t - start;
        var pos = delta/duration;
        if (delta <= duration) {
             draw(x1,y1,x2,y2, ease, pos)
             frame(run)
        }
    }   
}

function draw(x1,y1,x2,y2,ease, pos) {  //does the drawing
    var easepos= ease(pos)
    canvas.width = canvas.width;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.lineTo(x1 + (x2 - x1) * easepos, y1+ (y2- y1) * easepos);
    ctx.stroke();            
}

animate(10,10,150,100, 2000, easeing.bouncePast)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fqtGb/2/  -> demo

-- Andy

Comment: thanks andy, i managed to take my answer abit further http://jsbin.com/enobes/6   adding a cancelRequestAnimFrame function - http://notes.jetienne.com/2011/05/18/cancelRequestAnimFrame-for-paul-irish-requestAnimFrame.html    . like how you've added the ease, will try to include it!