# HTML5/Javascript moving an object across the screen at an angle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

For the past year or so I've been familiarizing myself with Javascript, and in an attempt to really learn the language thoroughly I decided to make an HTML5 game! The problem i've run into is that I have absolutely no idea how to move an image across the screen smoothly, and at an angle. I could move it at a forty five degree angle by moving it one pixel up/down the x axis and one pixel up/down the y axis, but that's just not specific enough. How would I go about moving it at a very specific angle? It seems to me that there would have to be a function that rounds it to the nearest pixel?

Not exactly sure... Any solution is will work fine, although a non-library specific explanation would be preferred!

Thanks!

Comment: Who said a pixel had to be a whole number?

Comment: Try this to prove it. Enter this code into chromes console for this page, and then hit enter and watch the top left of the screen.
`var el = document.createElement("div");
el.setAttribute("style","width:50px;height:50px;top:10px;left:10px;background-color:red;position:absolute;z-index:20");
var doc = $("body")[0];
doc.appendChild(el);
setInterval(function(){ 
 var val = el.style.left;
 val = val.substring(0,val.length - 2);
 val = parseFloat(val);
 val += 0.1;
 val += "px";
 el.style.left = val; 
 },25);`

Comment: Oh shoot! You kinda just blew my mind! Although, does this help me at all since a screen can't display a fraction of a pixel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to look at is a javascript implementation of [Linear Interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762877/html5-js-how-to-animate-straight-line-between-two-coordinates) (or `lerp`). Another name is `motion tween` but I believe that is more of an animation term than game development.

The idea is that you have two coordinates, the start, and the end, and a time that for the animation to occur, and you use linear interpolation to animate between the two.

From the Stack Question linked, [this article](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) explains a browser implementation that will allow you to do interpolation.

Comment: Thank you so much! In my case though, I don't have a set end. I suppose I should have mentioned that this is going to be used to create a little test game where you can fly around a 2d spaceship with the arrow keys "Asteroids" style. Will this be a problem or will I be able to create a "theoretical" end point?

Comment: You won't have an "end" end point, but you will have an end point for each frame. You will have a "speed" and an "angle". At each "frame" or run through the game loop, you need to recalculate the new "end point" based on the current start point, the angle, and the speed of your ship. After you calculate the end point, you would use `lerp` to actually move the ship element from start to finish over some time-delta.

Comment: Alright cool, I appreciate the reply! I'll definitely have to do my research, but your explanation makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I'm having serous trouble finding an answer. The first link you provided used the moveto() function to write a diagonal line. It'd be awesome if there was a way to replicate or re-purpose this function but it seems to only be applicable to writing lines. Not gonna lie, the second link went way over my head! Everything you posted makes complete sense, and I understand it in theory. My problem is that I have no idea what function to utilize. I need some sort of overarching formula since the number of pixels it moves will change depending on the frame...

Comment: It's no bother, but it sounds like there is a disconnect. Each frame your ship will move a fixed number of pixels. That number is based on the distance formula: `distance = speed*Time` So your frame is a fixed time. Lets start with "1 second per frame" So now you need to figure out the `speed.` Set this at `2 pixel per second` so `d = 2pixel/s * 1 second = 2 pixel` Now that you have the distance to move, you need to find the end point. This is based on the angle that the ship is moving. From there, you can use trig functions to get the X,Y coordinates for your end point.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are making a game in HTML5, you should try out the [Canvas element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas). Draw all your game inside a Canvas, instead of manipulating DOM elements. That being said, the principle for moving an image (inside a Canvas, or an image tag), would be to calculate the position with sin/cos + distance from the top left corner of the canvas/window.

Example:

```
160° (South by South-East, give or take), distance 130 pixels.
sin(160)*130
  = 44.462619
cos(160)*130
  = -122.160041
```

--> Top-left corner is at x=44, y=122 (since 44:-122 in a 0:0 bottom-left coordinates system translates to 44:122 in a 0:0 top-left coordinates system).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm guessing that calculating the sin/cos would give me my angle while applying the linear interpolation technique suggested by Alan would perform the actual movement?

Answer (score 0):

You will need trigonometry there :) For example if you want to move object to mouse cursor, then you have object coordinates and mouse coordinates and you should calculate X and Y step length (sorry for my english)

Comment: Well I'm moving it with arrow keys, so I don't know the end location like I would if I was moving it to where I clicked.